# Matrix image vs. Basis image

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, terminology

I'm just trying to understand the difference between questions - if something says "find the image of the matrix" vs. "find the basis of the image of the matrix" is there any difference?

And if so, when given a matrix, what is the difference between the two?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image $\text{Im}(A)$ of a matrix $A\in\mathbb{M}_{n\times m}(K)$ is a vector subspace of $K^n$, since for vectors $u,v\in K^m$ and scalars $\lambda,\mu\in K$ we have
$$\lambda Av+\mu Aw=A(\lambda v+\mu w).$$

Therefore, when you are told to show $\text{Im}(A)$, a good way to do so is, as with any other vector subspace, to show a basis for it.

Comment: So when solving, would my answers for image and image basis be the same?

Comment: @spage In practice, there are few ocassions in which you would give the image of $A$ without specifying one of its basis. So yes, if $\{b_1,\ldots,b_k\}$ is a basis for Im$(A)$, you would just say Im$(A)=$span$(b_1,\ldots,b_k)$, but with the warning that the basis and the space *are not the same*: the basis *generates* the space via its linear combinations, so the *span* of the basis is the space. Note that the basis is just a finite set

Comment: @spage Thank you for accepting my answer! It would be nice if you also upvoted it.

Comment: Thank your for your help, its much clearer now... unfortunately, as a new member, I can't upvote it because I have less than 15 reputation - if it goes up I definitely will!

Comment: @JoseBrox Great answer; however, I feel like it could be made more clear for novices by clarifying the $\mathbb{M}_{n\times m}(K)$ notation (perhaps just by giving a freshman-level example?). IMO someone familiar with this notation is already likely to know the answer and, conversely, someone who doesn't know the answer is (more) likely to be unfamiliar with the notation (and so confused by it). I would be happy to make the edit, with your approval, but don't think I could do as good of a job. +1 regardless.